# TeamCity - Aggregate multiple issues into the same build

Tags: teamcity, jira

Is it possible to build aggragating two or more issues into TeamCity?
In my example I need to build and deploy to my production server only sources from the same "Issue Key". I tried to group it from the Dashboard unsuccessfully.
[image]

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you want to take some subset of the commits and make a build from them?

Comment: @OlegRybak exaclty. I need to group them (in red) into a single build